# External names of parameters in Swift

Tags: swift, parameters, arguments, parameter-passing

My app crashes with NSInvalidArgumentException:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[*TtGC5Joker10PickerViewSS*
>   select:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7972a390'

I'm trying to use external name for argument

```
cell.pickerView.select(byKey: self.model.assignee.value)

/* ... */   

public func select(byKey key: T) {
}
```

Everything works fine when I remove external name from definition and call

```
public func select(_ key: T) {
}

/*...*/

cell.pickerView.select(self.model.assignee.value)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me as though this is due to namespace clashing.

Please check whether your `JokerPickerView` or any of it's superclasses have a function with the signature `select(:)` and if so I would recommend naming your function differently.

As it is your function appears to be poorly named according the Swift standards. An example of a better name function would be:

`selectOption(with key: T)`

if the things being selected are 'options'. Even just taking your attempted function name, a better way of doing it would have been:

`select(by key: T)`

However, due to the potential clashing, I would avoid calling a function `select`.